# Sync Data From Azure Blob Storage to AWS S3

Tags: azure, amazon-s3

How do I to keep a particular file in AWS in sync with the source file that is initially in my Azure blob storage?

Azure blob storage = **Source**

AWS = **Target**

I want to constantly keep both files in sync, by updating the file in AWS (Target) with the file in Azure blob storage (Source)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the open-source Node.js package `azure-blob-to-s3` for the migration of the content from Azure Blob Storage to Amazon S3. An example CLI command is as follows:

```
azure-s3 \
  --concurrency 10 \
  --azure-connection "..." \
  --azure-container my-container \
  --aws-bucket my-bucket \
  --aws-prefix my-prefix
```

Github page of azure-s3: https://github.com/bendrucker/azure-blob-to-s3

Also, this blog page describes the use-case in detail: https://github.com/bendrucker/azure-blob-to-s3https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/one-way-to-migrate-data-from-azure-blob-storage-to-amazon-s3/

Comment: This is not totally clear @adp 
Can you please share screenshot or environment where this command can work?
I will appreciate a detailed guide, Thanks

Comment: After installing the tool with `npm install --save azure-blob-to-s3`, you will be able to use it in a bash environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily sync your data from Azure blob storage to s3 with ***RClone*** as described here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/migrate-data-from-microsoft-azure-blob-to-amazon-s3-by-using-rclone.html

**Example: copy**

This command copies data from the source Azure Blob container to the destination S3 bucket.

```
rclone copy AZStorageAccount:blob-container s3:examplebucket-01
```

**Example: sync**

This command synchronizes data between the source Azure Blob container and the destination S3 bucket.

```
rclone sync AZStorageAccount:blob-container s3:examplebucket-01
```